# .Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

New to .NET Core.

What am I doing wrong? Here is my controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class customerController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/values
    //[HttpGet]
    //public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    //{
    //    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    //}

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public customer Get(int id)
    {
        var repo = new customerRepository();
        return repo.GetCustomerOnPhone(id);
    }
}
```

I am able to call the API with this URL

`http://localhost:51375/api/customer/8172858817`

I hit the breakpoint in GET method, but Id is always zero. I cannot get the method to read the value which is being passed from URL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Max int is `2147483647` Your value is too large. change to `long`

Comment: Or use Guid for Id's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int MaxValue = 2147483647`

Your value `8172858817` is too large.

Either use a smaller value or change parameter to `long`

```
[HttpGet("{id:long}")]
public IActionResult Get(long id) {
    var repo = new customerRepository();
    customer model = repo.GetCustomerOnPhone(id);
    return Ok(model);
}
```

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core : Route Constraint Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#route-constraint-reference)

Comment: This works. If I change the method name to GetCustomerByPhone, I do not hit breakpoint. The new URL I'm using is  http://localhost:51375/api/customer/GetCustomerByPhone/8172858817 . If I use only GET as my method name, I am able to hit the break point. Why so?

Comment: You would need to update route template. `[HttpGet("GetCustomerByPhone/{id})"`]